# What types of flags does this register carry?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an Unsigned Number

- in registers `%rdi/edi/di` I have 0xFFFE
- in registers `%rsi/esi/si` I have 0x4.

The objective is to do `addw %di, %si`

Firstly, I want to know... what values are put into %si and why? I'm still not 100% clear on that.

Secondly, I need to know: What types of flags does this one contain? I have read what makes a flag appear, but its not entirely clear at all which flags appear or why even when the book tells me point blank.

Comment: assembly must be tagged with the architecture. And a register doesn't carry any flags

Comment: I think this is ATT in C. Also, it doesn't? So, what does carry the flags?

Comment: You can think of flags as 1 bit registers.

Comment: See [Art of Assembly eflags register](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/HelloWorlda3.html#998367) and more generally all editions [Art of Assembly](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/)

Comment: AT&T is a syntax, not architecture

Comment: @The_Senate The flags are stored in the separate `flags` register.  This register is not directly accessibly as an operand but it can be pushed and popped with `pushf` and `popf` or moved to/from `ah` with `sahf` and `lahf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unsigned numbers you can zero extend it by adding any number of 0s in front of it. So `RSI` here is `0x0000000000000004`. `SI` is the lower 16 bit of `RSI` so it is `0x0004`.

```
RDI is 000000000000FFFE 
EDI is         0000FFFE 
DI  is             FFFE

RSI is 0000000000000004
ESI is         00000004
SI  is             0004
```

All the registers store the number and don't contain any flag. In fact, the CPU cannot even tell whether a number is **signed** or **unsigned**.

The CPU has only one flags register, and it normally can only be set according to the result of an arithmetic or comparison operation. For example, moving `0xFFFE` to `DI` has no effect on the flags. You have to use `testw %di, %di` to compare `DI` to itself and then the flags will be changed accordingly.

```
MOV  DI, 0xFFFE ; flags are not changed
TEST DI, DI     ; flags are changed according to the result of TEST
JZ   .A         ; will not jump because ZF (Zero Flag) is not set because DI is not zero
JS   .B         ; will jump because SF (Sign Flag) is set because the highest bit of DI is 1
```

Comment: you should avoid using 16-bit registers, because they need the 66h prefix, resulting in **longer instructions**, and they are also **slower** due to the partial register stall and the microcode decoding step. 32-bit registers are often better [On 32-bit CPUs, is an 'integer' type more efficient than a 'short' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163254/995714), [Why run 16-bit programs on x86 operating systems get slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20145903/995714)

Comment: [Why are mov ah,bh and mov al, bl together much faster than single instruction mov ax, bx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031671/995714), [Understanding partial-register slowdowns from mov instead of movzx instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47052342/995714), [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502/995714), [What is a Partial Flag Stall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49867597/995714)